# Can I check whether `shared_from_this` is safe to call?

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, ownership-semantics

When calling `shared_from_this` from within types that inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), very bad things (TM) can happen, if `this` is not currently held by a `shared_ptr` object (typically, the application crashing). Is it possible in C++14 (not 17) to check whether it is safe?

Edit: Withouth using exceptions or try/catch.

Comment: It seems unusual to me to use `enable_shared_from_this` with a type where some objects will be owned by shared pointers and some won't. When using `enable_shared_from_this`, I usually make it impossible to create the object except using public static `create` and `clone` functions. Maybe enforcing that could work with your design and avoid the issue?

Comment: They are all held by a `shared_ptr` in the end, but even when using `make_shared`, during the ctor, the object is not yet held by anything. And if that constructor calls a few functions, they might end up trying to access `shared_from_this`. I have the problem in my `invariant` function.

Comment: I can now see the hole that you describe. Perhaps the c++17 weak_from_this() method is safer, i.e. could safely return a null weak pointer before the object is make_share()d?

Comment: Is the **bad thing** just when calling shared_from_this(), or is it from using that shared pointer without first checking it is not null? If the latter, then shared_from_this() is the function you are looking for!

Comment: @GemTaylor: Yes, I am aware of `weak_from_this`, but I'm currently bound to C++14. The "bad thing" is that calling `shared_from_this` is undefined in this situation. But anyway, the backtrace indicates that the throw originates from the call itself.

Comment: If it isn't owned, do you have a way out? Or do you just want to put a diagnostic and abort?

Answer (score 1):

It is an implementation detail, but could you do something nasty with the internal friend declaration:

```
template<typename _Tp1>
friend void
__enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<>& __pn,
                 const enable_shared_from_this* __pe,
                 const _Tp1* __px) noexcept
```

Implement your own version with _Tp1 as weak_ptr<>*, that returns the weak pointer [Actually not quite as __px is a const pointer, so you need an extra indirection to lose the const, or if you are being dirty anyway, cast it away!]
. Wrap it all in a class that you then derive from instead of enable_shared_from_this:

```
#if >= C++17
using enable_shared_from_this_c17 = enable_shared_from_this;
#else

template<typename _Tp>
enable_shared_from_this_c17: public enable_shared_from_this<_Tp>
{

  weak_ptr<_Tp> weak_from_this()
  {
    weak_ptr<_Tp> rv; auto rv2 = &rv;
    __enable_shared_from_this_helper(*(const __shared_count<>*)nullptr, this, &rv2);
    return rv;
  }
}
#endif
```

Now, you have an implementation of weak_from_this() in c++14. Yes, it is a nasty cludge, but it is just until you upgrade to 17.

Alternatively, just catch the exception!

Third alternative - add an instantiate template wrapper that sets "constructed" in a wrapper for enable_shared_from_this that wraps shared_from_this() so it fails until the constructed flag has been set.

```
enable_shared_from_this
    safe_shared_from_this
        your interfaces
            your_implementation
                constructed<your_implementation>
```

Of course, this is imperfect if the class is ever used without immediately assigning to a shared_ptr.

Comment: Ouch, this is certanly a cool hack. But I guess just setting a flag in my postConstruction method or just at the end of the ctor is the easiest. When posting the question, I thought maybe there is a way to check this already in C++14 and I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is a main reason "they" added weak_from_this

Answer (score 0):

If `this` is not held by `shared_ptr` then you cannot do anything. From cppreference: [It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) Here is example of that:

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass;

std::shared_ptr<MyClass> global;

void resetGlobal()
{
    global = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
}

class MyClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>
{
public:
    void use()
    {
        resetGlobal();
        shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    global = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    global->use();
    return 0;
}
```

At the beginning of `use` method `shared_from_this` should be fine (except in multithread environment without mutexes) but after calling any function that can alter `shared_ptr`s elsewhere you cannot be sure. After calling `resetGlobal` function `this` is simply destroyed and any access to it is undefined behavior so could result in segmentation fault.

The only way to be sure that through entire method call `shared_from_this` is valid is to make temporary `shared_ptr` at the beginning of call:

```
void use()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> tmp = shared_from_this();
    resetGlobal();
    shared_from_this();
}
```

or

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> tmp = global;
    global->use();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any other object in your program has access to your object's raw `this` pointer, then you are using `shared_ptr` entirely the wrong way.

Any pointer to your object to be used externally to your object MUST be wrapped in a `shared_ptr<YourObject>` value instance, no exceptions.

Comment: _"Any pointer to your object ... MUST be wrapped in a shared_ptr<YourObject> value instance"_  I don't agree with that.  A `shared_ptr` is more costly, but that cost is justified if it may need to change object lifetime.